# Why can't I set the navigation controller background color in the storyboard?

Tags: ios, xcode, ios7, xcode5, uistoryboard

I don't understand why the background color setting in the storyboard doesn't work for my navigation controller? (See picture)

http://ctrlv.in/299323

I have here set it to bright red but as you can see it does nothing in the storyboard or to the app when I build it.

Any thoughts?

I know I can set the color programmatically, and this is what I am currently doing. However, it would be nice to see the changes in the storyboard so I don't have to build the app every time I make a color change to see the difference.

Comment: I solved a similar problem before by setting it in code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes you can. Notice that you're changing `UIView` properties not Navigation bar. Look at the screen below:

[image]

You have to set **Bar Tint** property.

Comment: Bar Tint won't effect anything